# RestKit "Cannot perform relationship mapping without a data source" from local JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

(For more complete code, see my gist: https://gist.github.com/AlistairIsrael/6521763)

I'm trying to map a "has-many" relationship from a local JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "fruits",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "apple",
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have code based on the sample code on the wiki:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#performing-a-mapping

*Client.m*

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"collections" ofType: @"json"];
NSError* e;
NSString* json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
id data = [RKNSJSONSerialization objectFromData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&e];

NSMutableArray* collections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[data count]];
for (id record in data) {
    Collection* collection = [Collection new];
    RKMappingOperation* op = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:data destinationObject:collections mapping:[Collection mapping]];
    [op start];
    [collections addObject:collection];
}

return [NSArray arrayWithArray:collections];
```

This works fine when all I want to map is a 'flat' array of objects. However, I've run into a wall when trying to map an array of nested objects—objects that themselves have a property that is a collection of other objects.

*Collection.m*

```
@interface Collection : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray* items;

@implementation Collection
+ (RKMapping*) mapping {
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Collection class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

    RKPropertyMapping* itemsMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"items" toKeyPath:@"items" withMapping:[Item mapping]]

    // Commenting out the following line works, but no items
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:itemsMapping];

    return mapping;
}
```

If I comment out line 13 in `Collection mapping:`, then the code in `Client.m` gives me an array of `Collection` (with no `items`).

But as it is, when I try to add the `RKRelationshipMapping` for the items property of a `Collection`, I keep getting:

> Cannot perform relationship mapping without a data source

I've also tried using an `RKMapperOperation` similar to the code in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/kmc239/5846568

To no avail—I get an empty `NSArray`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`dataSource` refers to the property of the `RKMappingOperation` which provides it with an object conforming to `RKMappingOperationDataSource`. This allows you to implement `mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:` so that you can find existing objects which match the supplied parameters and return those objects (instead of new objects always being created).